# React.forwardRef warning but no ref passed or how to pass custom component to another component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, forward-reference

I want to pass a custom input proponent to another proponent this way:

```
<FormTextField
     name="startTime"
     label="startTime"
     type="time"
     error={!!errors.startTime}
     CustomTextField={TextFieldColorTimeIcon} <-- custom TextField
     ...
/>
```

The code for FormTextField:

```
export default function FormTextField({ name, CustomTextField, ...other }) {
    const { control } = useFormContext();
    let LocalCustomTextField = CustomTextField ? CustomTextField : TextField;

    return (
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
            render={
                ({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (<LocalCustomTextField {...field} fullWidth error={!!error} helperText={error?.message} {...other} />)
              }
        />
      );
    }
```

And the code for TextFieldColorIcon:

```
export function TextFieldColorIcon({ sx, ...other }: TextFieldColorIconProps) {
    return <TextField
        sx={{
            ...sx,
            '& input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator': {
                filter:
                    'invert(41%) sepia(24%) saturate(301%) hue-rotate(166deg) brightness(101%) contrast(89%)',
            },
        }}
        {...other} />
}
```

But I've got warning:
**Warning: Function proponents cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
Check the render method of `Controller`.
at TextFieldColorIcon
at Controller
at FormTextField
at div**

despite of the fact that there is no ref passed.
What is the reason of this warning and am I passing custom TextFieldColorIcon right way?

Comment: What is `Controller`?

Comment: Controller is a react-hook-form middleware to catch and process form events:
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

Comment: `Controller` is trying to pass a `ref` to your `TextFieldColorIcon` component, but it is a function component and it is not wrapped with `React.forwardRef`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html.

Comment: Thank you, @RyanCogswell! I wrapped TextFieldColorIcon in forwardRef and it works without error. Controller has hidden implementation and it was not clear what and why it is passing in its render property

Comment: But some frustration persists: render property is a function (it's shown above):
({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (<LocalCustomTextField {...field} fullWidth error={!!error} helperText={error?.message} {...other} />) 

. And in this function I in neither way am not passing any ref to LocalCustomTextField